# Why are there two different ways to solve the same problem but two different answers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was talking to a professor, and we both were stumbled on the problem of: $\sqrt{\sqrt{x^{2}}-1}=2$

My professor's thought process was that you would immediately square both sides to get $\sqrt{x^{2}-1}=4$ then solve to get $x= \pm  5$

My thought process was that you could simplify the $\sqrt{x^{2}}$ first which would the leave the problem as $\sqrt{x-1}=2$ and then you would solve and be left with $x=5$. This way of the solution proves that $x$ can not be negative $5$ because the $x^{2}$ becomes $x$.

When we plugged these two equations into the calculator $\sqrt{\sqrt{x^{2}}-1}=y$ and $y=\sqrt{x-1}$ the calculator showed us that both problems were not similar. One had two solutions the other had only one.

Essentially, how is it that the same problem can have +/- as an answer while the other can be only +. Technically, aren't both problems the same? Just one is more simplified than the other. I feel like this has something to do with a deeper level of PEMDAS

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. Squaring and then taking the square root gets rid of any negative sign that might be there, so you lose all negative solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The solution of your professor is correct; the answer is $+5$ and $-5$.
If one translates this problem into precise mathematics, it amounts to asking “For which real numbers $x\in\mathbb R$ is $\sqrt{\sqrt{x^{2}}-1}=2$”. One can directly see that this is fulfilled by $\pm 5$. 
You are losing the second solution when you assume that $\sqrt{x^2}=x$. This is not the case; instead $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. So doing your approach correctly leads to
$$ 
\sqrt{\sqrt{x^{2}}-1}=2~~\Leftrightarrow~~\sqrt{|x|-1}=2~~\Leftrightarrow~~|x|-1=4~~\Leftrightarrow~~|x|=5
$$

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that $\sqrt{x^2}$ does not simplify to $x$ but actually to $|x|$. Then when plugged $-5$ in the expression the result is
$$\sqrt{\sqrt{(-5)^2} - 1} = \sqrt{\sqrt{25} - 1} = \sqrt{5 - 1} = 2$$

A final consideration is that usually each squared sign or absolute value operation will add one extra solution to the problem. In this case since you have one squaring operation (the square roots don't decrease the number of solutions) it is expected to exist two solutions for the problem. The one you found is one of them, but your teacher's solution shows both

Comment: This makes more sense now. We did not realize that /sqrt{x^{2}} is the absolute value of x rather than simply x. This would explain the different solutions.